# Rabl model extends

Tags: json, extends, rabl

I am creating some json outputs for some of my Rails models.

I have two models: Piece and Set. The relationships are:

> A Pieces belongs to a Set

and

> A Set has many Pieces

Now, I have started to write Rabl json templates for both models and each outputs their relationship items, eg: Set also outputs it's Pieces and A Pieces outputs the Set it belongs to.

I ahve done this separately for now due to this issue but wondered what the best way of resolving this issue is as I would like to convert it so that the template for a Set allows the Pieces in it to use the template for a Piece, However, that Piece template also outputs it's set which would use the template for a Set and it would keep looping and fall over.

Is there a way around this?

Since writing this question I have gone ahead and built it out and yes, this issue has actually occurred. The result I get is a json file with a 500 Internal Server Error.

Is there a way I can conditionally add the child Pieces only if the set Show json is being rendered but leave them out if the Index json is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using local variables.

I passed a local variable into the extend to determine whether to display the inner content or not.